# Magento 2 : Why product showing different names in admin area?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

Same product having different names:

> Products/Catalog:

Please see 1st product in list(9766) -> Name : **bbbbbbb**

[image]

> Same product in edit mode(9766):

Name : **GGGGG**

[image]

When I tried custom query on my database getting following result:

[image]

Tested after clearing generation and cache.

How to solve this now?

Comment: As per your query result you can see that your `product_id` is assigned to 2 different `store_ids`

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal **0-> admin and 1 -> default** But why it's showing different for grid and detail page.

Comment: Try this: change the View in Admin ->Products ->Catalog -> Default View

Comment: @Nitesh, could you solve this issue? I am also facing same

Comment: @jafarpinjar You can follow coments.